# Database Creating table error

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Trying to create a table

```
create table Properties(pID number, pAddress varchar(60) not null, oID
 number not null, cID number, Primary Key(pID, oID, cID),leaseExp varchar(16));
```

Table created

But when I run the next command I get the following error.

```
create table Client(cID number, cName varchar(16), mRent number(8,2), 
 Primary Key(cID, cName), Foreign Key(cID) references Properties(cID));
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's because you're referencing cId from Properties as your foreign key in Clients, which is not unique or a primary key of Properties. It is part of a primary key, but there are two other columns in that primary key. So, your foreign key in the Client table could be referencing multiple records in the Properties table.

Ideally, Properties should have a foreign key of cId referencing the Client table, since cId would be (I assume) each client's unique ID. Also, you'll probably want to specify that cId must be unique in the client table, as I'm assuming each client will have a unique cId. Without this, you won't be able to have a foreign key referencing cId in the Client table from the Properties table.

Also, you should probably create the Client table before the Properties table, since Clients probably own Properties, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, yep adding them the other way helps and making properties have the foreign keys and not client

Comment: Glad I could help :)